# String concatenation within INFORMIX-SQL "Perform" screens

Tags: informix

How can I concatenate two char columns within a perform screen?

example:

| table | sample |
| --- | --- |
| col1 | char(1) |
| col2 | char(1) |

after edit/add of sample

```
let label_3 = sample.col1 + sample.col2
```

.. this didn't work, I even tried using subscripts for the 2 cols but no dice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a simple way to do it.  Your closest approach would be a custom C function to do the concatenation:

```
LET label_3 = CONCATENATE(sample.col1, sample.col2)
```

That, of course, relies on you having a custom Perform runner with a concatenate function added to it.

Perform pre-dates the addition of the '||' string concatenation operator into SQL and does not support it.

The alternative is to use an Informix 4GL (I4GL) program instead.  You can do a lot of things in I4GL that you cannot do in ISQL - at the cost of writing the code.

Comment: which is ridiculous. The lack of string manipulation functions in IDS is a bit of a running joke - running as in a PITA. What if we need to send in an encoded string with row ids for example and wish to return a rowset. IDS = I Dont Seem to care for the developer (tenuous)